# Getting errors while truncating Partitioned Table using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am just doing some POC on table partitioning on existing tables, but I am stuck at this level, when I run the script shown below. Please give me suggestions

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [AdventureWorks2012].[dbo].[SalesOrderDetail_DataNEW] 
     WITH (PARTITION (3));
```

I am getting an error like:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, and what's the compatibility level of your database? Truncating partitions is supported only from  SQL Server 2016 onwards. (Even then, the correct syntax uses `PARTITIONS`, but the error message here suggests you're just on an earlier version/compat level).

Comment: Sql server 2012

Comment: Right, just saw it in the title. :-P Well, there's your answer in any case -- SQL Server 2012 does not support this. At best you can `ALTER TABLE SWITCH` the partition, truncate, and switch back.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for the information i have been thinking only on syntactical error .i didn't think about version compatibility

Answer (score 1):

The name of your table is wrong --

Here is a syntax diagram

```
[ { database_name .[ schema_name ] . | schema_name . } ]  
table_name
```

add the database and table name to that schema name or take out the brackets

here is the current documentation location
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi I changed the script as you suggested but still i am getting the same error .Thanks for the quick response sir

Comment: @Sreenu131 -- yep makes sense.. if you read the documentation on the link it seems the WITH part is only supported in versions after 2016